# Failure: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> Exception of type 'PushSharp.Apple.NotificationFailureException' was thrown

Tags: ios, .net, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am using **PushSharp** in my application for sending push notification. It's working fine for android.

For apple iOS - it's not working, we are using development certificate file with password.
Initially we have used wrong password then later we found that issue and fixed.

It's getting bellow error message

```
Channel Created for: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService Failure: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> Exception of type 'PushSharp.Apple.
NotificationFailureException' was thrown. -> {"aps":{"alert":"Hello World!","badge":7,"sound":"default"}}
```

**Error status code:8**

**Error Description: Invalid token**

App developed by one of our vendor and push notification we are doing from our side.
vendor sending push notification using some PHP code it's working.
To push notifications they were using PHP server with Laravel framework and library:https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

I have installed that app on my iPhone's device and they send test push notification it's working fine.

But i was try to send using Pushsharp framework it's not working.

They saying development certificate file is correct it's working fine.

I have tried all possible option from my end but i am not getting any clue why its behaving odd with development certificate .p12. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Code that we used for development:

```
var push = new PushBroker();
    var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "xxxxPass.p12"));
    push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "xxxx12345")); //Extension method
    push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                               .ForDeviceToken("a51b4e80d12df0946d10413991ce1f7ab57c05bab8a292fc703ded34ce77b91f")
                               .WithAlert("Hello World!")
                               .WithSound("default")
                               .WithBadge(7));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been because of invalid certificate file.

The following steps are done from my side in IOS app.

1. Created a new Xcode project Single View Application with Object-c Class.
2. Drog and Droped the WebView control and mapped to view controller.
3. In the “ViewController.h” file I have added below code.
   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *site;
4. In the “AppDelegate.h” file I have added below code.

> - (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@”https://www.xxxxx.com”];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_site loadRequest:requestURL];
}

5. In the “AppDelegate.m” file I have added below code.

> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>     // Register for Remote Notifications
>      if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
>     {
>         // iOS 8 Notifications
>         [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
> ```
>
> settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
>   UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
>   categories:nil]];
>
> ```
>         [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         // iOS < 8 Notifications
>         [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
>          (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
>     }
>
>     return YES;
> }
> ```

6. In the xxxx Developer apple account – created a new App ID
   Name:xxx
   Bundle ID: com.xxxxdubai.xxxx
   Push Notification Enabled for Development.
   Created new Development SSL Certificate using following below steps.
   Created certificate using CRS file Keychain Access ->Certificate Assitant -> Reqest a Certificate From a Certificate Authority… that’s generated CertificateSigningReq…Request file.
   Uploaded CRS file under iOS Cerfiicate file and generated.

It’s automatically created under Certificates Development section
Name: com.xxxxdubai.xxxx
Type:APNs Development iOS

7. And then created Provisional Profiles for Development
   Name: XXXX Development
   Type: Ios Development
   App ID: selected xxxx app id
   Certificate: selected xxxx iOS development
   Devices: selected my velus-iPhone device

Generated Provisioning Profiles successfully.

8. And then I did added Provisioning profile to Keychain access login and exported apns.dev.cert.p12 file with password.
9. In the Xcode APP project Build  settings are changed to selected the Provisioning Profile (the one I did exported and registered)
10. Selected simulator as My your’s-iPhone device and Run the project it’s successfully installed and lunched the app on my mobile.
11. Automatically first time alert message shown from app for registering push notification with APNS server and the new device token received and logged to displayed in the debugging area.
12. Tested with PushShap framework with the new certificate apns.dev.cert.p12 and new device id push notification works successfully.